# Javascript Framework for creation and layout of interactive graphs (nodes an arrows)

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, javascript-framework

Are there any javascript frameworks out there that support creating of interactive nodes and arrows ?

I would like to be able to define nodes (with some grahics and text)
and (directed) arrows that connect them that also have text on the arrow itself (or near it).

I will want the nodes to be able to render them selves based on minimum intersections of arrows and possible other types of hinting, like providing a number to each node and having nodes with lower numbers be located higher (or lower) in the display.

It would eb also nice if the auto layout mechanism would also support the ability to fix the locations of some of the nodes and layout only the non-fixed ones.

nodes and arrows should be optionally drag-able and click-able firing events as required.

I will user raphael if I don't find anything better. but would be happy to save myself some coding time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try these:

- http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html
- http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/